# Can't print on virtual machine with java code

Tags: java, printing, virtual-machine

i am running a virtual machine with VMware 9.0. I added the printers via the Settings tab in the VM. To see that my printers are availabe on my vm i wrote a little program:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;

public class ShowPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintService lookupDefaultPrintService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        if (lookupDefaultPrintService != null)
            System.out.println("default: " + lookupDefaultPrintService.getName());
        else {
            System.out.println("default: null");
        }

        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        for (PrintService service : services)
            if (service != null)
                System.out.println("- " + service.getName());
        else
            System.out.println("- null");
    }
}
```

This works well and i get some printers listed (including the one i want to use). I wrote a little program which should print something:

```
package virtualMachinePrinter;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;

public class MyPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("C:/temp/printtest.txt");
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

        DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, flavor, null);
        try {
            job.print(doc, null);
        } catch (PrintException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("Printing done...");
    }
}
```

On my local machine this works just well, and if i change the default printer, it prints to it. On the virtual machine this works not as intended. The XPS document writer doesn't even start. If i try the same with pdf-printer, the page setup opens at least (but nothing is printed). If i start the little programm above inside a web-application on a Tomcat 7, it doesn't print anything. Independent of which default printer is used. In both cases the print order is added to the printing queue. But only outside of a Tomcat something is printed. Inside the Tomcat nothing is printed. I am using no security manager in my Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two actions solved this problem:
1. I had to use 32-bit version of Java. This fixed the problem printing with XPS document writer.
2. I had to update my printer drivers. This fixed the problem printing with the printer.